# API Management Basic Authentication

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an Azure API Management, added a logic app as back end API. Now I want to enable basic authentication for the API Management so that when client will call the logic app url which is protected by API Management need to provide username and password. I am familiar with access restriction policy of API Management , now my question is where  and how to set basic authentication credentials in the APIM?

Answer (score 11):

Here is a code snippet to set up basic auth wuth username="someUser" and password="ThePassw0rd"

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-variable name="isAuthOk" 
value="@(context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") 
            && context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].Contains(
            "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(
                  Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("someUser:ThePassw0rd")
                )
              )
              )" />
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("isAuthOk"))">
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized" />
                    <set-header name="WWW-Authenticate" exists-action="override">
                        <value>Basic realm="someRealm"</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>Wrong username or password</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Very helpful !! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use below code snippet 
https://github.com/Azure/api-management-policy-snippets/blob/master/examples/Perform%20basic%20authentication.policy.xml

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization")==null || context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").Length<1 || context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").AsBasic().UserId!="{{UserId}}" || context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").AsBasic().Password!="{{Password}}")">
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="401" reason="Not authorized" />
            </return-response>
        </when>
    </choose>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="delete" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

And incase you want to store password to keyvault you can use below policy instead of above

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <send-request ignore-error="false" timeout="20" response-variable-name="passwordResponse" mode="new">
        <set-url>https://mykvname.vault.azure.net/secrets/MySecretValue/?api-version=7.0</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://vault.azure.net" />
    </send-request>
    <rewrite-uri template="/" copy-unmatched-params="true" />
    <set-backend-service base-url="https://testservice/" />
    <authentication-basic username="myusername" password="@{ var secret = ((IResponse)context.Variables["passwordResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(); return secret["value"].ToString(); }" />
</inbound>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this , I have added a access restriction policy for basic authentication and put a credentials  in the policy.

Sample Policy

Basic B64Credentials

Answer (score 0):

A bit simpler solution is to use `check-header` policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/check-header-policy

```
<set-variable name="credentials" value="username:password" />
<check-header name="Authorization" failed-check-httpcode="401" failed-check-error-message="Not authorized" ignore-case="false">
    <value>@("Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)context.Variables["credentials"])))</value>
</check-header>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question, you can set the policy in:
Apis -> All Apis or specifc -> Design -> Inbound processing -> Code View.
Inside policies/inbound you can insert:

authentication-basic username="username" password="password"

See more in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#Basic

Comment: Thanks for your response , but this is not my actual question. My question is  how to set basic authentication for API management.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to API management, I would recommend using an API Gateway like APACHE APISIX, this article explains how to use Apache APISIX to implement Centralized Authentication Management.
https://medium.com/@ApacheAPISIX/using-apache-apisix-and-authing-to-implement-centralized-authentication-management-6a5f3af1a674

Hope it helps someone.