# The Azure Api Rule doesn´t apply using default assistant with authentication-basic and authentication-certificate

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

I´m adding an inbound processing policy rule to apply all Azure API Service methods. Using policies wizard I find authentication-basic that I wrote in next lines.

```
<inbound>
     <base />
     <authentication-basic username="myUserName" password="myPassword" />
</inbound>
```

So, Why it doesn´t apply when I invoke from Postman using Basic Auth. Allways the response is 200-OK, and it doesn´t mather if I change the user and password. Allways the response it's OK. I check the header request from client and It´s adding the correct Authentication user:password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This policy is used to add basic credentials to a call APIM will make to a backend to fulfill the request. If you want to check credentials sent by client to APIM you could use policy expressions to look into `context.Request.Headers` to see if auth header is present. Like in this question: [API Management Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49479416/181556)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know what if refers about this rule.