# Azure API Gateways Basic Auth

Tags: azure

Does Azure Api Gateways support Basic Auth? I can't find it at [feature list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/features). Is there any possibility to integrate it with Key Vault and make Basic Auth with SSL termination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Application Gateway does not support Basic Auth. Does not support [any sort of client authentication](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/19473664-authentication-support-for-application-gateway), except certificate authentication for the backend bool.

If your application is an API, you can evaluate [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/). This can be used to do basic authentication [for your clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479416/api-management-basic-authentication) and [for your backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#Basic), though I am not sure how well you can link it with KeyVault. It should work on the ARM template level using [dynamic ID references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-cli#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id) at least.